# Magento 2.3.4 installation stuck at 58%

Tags: failed-installation, magento-2.3

[screenshot of the installation progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nbZp.png)

Installing Magento 2.3.4 on a centos 8 machine, Apache 2.4, Php 7.3.16, Mysql 8.0.17, installation stuck at 58%, have already tried max_execution_time=18000 & max_input_time=1800 on the /etc/php.ini file, did not work

Code on the bottom of the console log:

```
Upgrading data...
[ERROR] PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1419 You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable) in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(91): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(107): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\{closure}()
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(92): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->tryExecute(Object(Closure))
#3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#5 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('CREATE TRIGGER ...', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(546): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('CREATE TRIGGER ...', Array)
#7 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(634): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('CREATE TRIGGER ...', Array)
#8 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql/Interceptor.php(141): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->multiQuery('CREATE TRIGGER ...', Array)
#9 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(3944): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor->multiQuery('CREATE TRIGGER ...')
#10 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql/Interceptor.php(1220): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->createTrigger(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Trigger))
#11 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Mview/View/Subscription.php(125): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor->createTrigger(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Trigger))
#12 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Mview/View.php(204): Magento\Framework\Mview\View\Subscription->create()
#13 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer.php(291): Magento\Framework\Mview\View->subscribe()
#14 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer/DependencyDecorator.php(192): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer->setScheduled(true)
#15 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/google-shopping-ads/Setup/UpgradeData.php(147): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\DependencyDecorator->setScheduled(true)
#16 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(992): Magento\GoogleShoppingAds\Setup\UpgradeData->upgrade(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext))
#17 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(879): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data', Array)
#18 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures(Array)
#19 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(368): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#20 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
#21 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(84): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
#22 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#23 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#24 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(116): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#25 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#26 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#27 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#28 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#29 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/index.php(39): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#30 {main}

Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1419 You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable), query was: CREATE TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_product_entity FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `scconnector_google_feed_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:110
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(92): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->tryExecute(Object(Closure))
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('CREATE TRIGGER ...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(546): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('CREATE TRIGGER ...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(634): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('CREATE TRIGGER ...', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql/Interceptor.php(141): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->multiQuery('CREATE TRIGGER ...', Array)
#7 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(3944): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor->multiQuery('CREATE TRIGGER ...')
#8 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql/Interceptor.php(1220): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->createTrigger(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Trigger))
#9 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Mview/View/Subscription.php(125): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor->createTrigger(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Trigger))
#10 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Mview/View.php(204): Magento\Framework\Mview\View\Subscription->create()
#11 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer.php(291): Magento\Framework\Mview\View->subscribe()
#12 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer/DependencyDecorator.php(192): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer->setScheduled(true)
#13 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/google-shopping-ads/Setup/UpgradeData.php(147): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\DependencyDecorator->setScheduled(true)
#14 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(992): Magento\GoogleShoppingAds\Setup\UpgradeData->upgrade(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext))
#15 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(879): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data', Array)
#16 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures(Array)
#17 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(368): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#18 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
#19 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(84): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
#20 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#21 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#22 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(116): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#23 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#24 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#25 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#26 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#27 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/index.php(39): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#28 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

please open terminal and give below command in Linux or Ubuntu:

sudo chmod -R 777 *

this command is ask for super user password
give the super user password and installtion was going further.